# CSS: How to align a division with the center of another division?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am new for web design. I am trying to making a box including an icon and a link. When the screen is laptop, the link should be in the left of the icon and align with its center vertically; when screen is tablet and mobile phone, the icon should be under the bottom of the icon and align with its center horizontally. And the icon is much bigger than the link. Here are the code and images links:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
             <span class="info-box-icon"><i class="mega-octicon octicon-server"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div  class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
            <a class="side-box-link" href="workflow-summary" style="vertical-align:middle;">Work Flow</a>
        </div>  
    </div>  
</div>
```

image links:

- bg and md:
  http://ww3.sinaimg.cn/bmiddle/77f9deafgw1evmq9c8z5tj206703amx6.jpg
- sm and xs:
  http://ww3.sinaimg.cn/bmiddle/77f9deafgw1evmq9cxdttj2045041gll.jpg

I've tried many method but still cannot make the link  align with the icon's center vertically, and the link is always align in top of the box. The methods I've tried:

1. Use table, and set the icon and link as two table data: they can align as
   what I want, but since they are two column, the link cannot move
   down when the screen size change.
2. Use table, put them in same line: align in the box top.
3. Use list: align in the box top.
4. Use margin in CSS: align well in md and bg screen but the icon and
   link will have gap in sm and xs as well.
5. Use "vertical-align:middle" in CSS: just not working

   What should I do? Any advice will be appreciate, thank you!

Comment: Can you create a demo of the current output?

Comment: The two links are the images of current output, first one is in md and bg screen, the second one is in sm and xs screen. Thank you!

Comment: If I use your current code, I just get plain text. You should be able to reproduce the issue here which will be easier for us to debug :) Try Bootply.com

Answer (score 2):

You can use Flexbox, there is a nice guide here [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Also take a look at this this example I made for you, hope it can help you out.

Html code:

```
<div class="box">
<div class="row">
    <div class="icon">
         <span class="info-box-icon"><i class="mega-octicon octicon-server"></i></span>
    </div>
    <div class="link">
        <a class="side-box-link" href="workflow-summary" style="vertical-align:middle;">Work Flow</a>
    </div>  
</div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
.row {
display: flex;
align-items: center;

}
.icon {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: salmon ;
}
.link{
    padding: 10px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

@media (max-width: 450px) {
    .row {
        flex-direction: column;
    }   
}
```

I did use fixed sizes with the icon to illustrate, but it'll work with any size.

Take a look at this live example [JSFiddle Flex Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tinmarin60/rgdxs4fq/)

Comment: Thank you so much!! This works so well. But do you have any idea about why those "align" properties in CSS not working in this case?

Comment: If you reproduce what you have done, maybe we can see whats going on. What i can tell you is that you souldn't use tables for layout. Cheers!